# How do I enable MySQL undo log encryption?

Tags: mysql, encryption

I have set `innodb_undo_log_encrypt=ON` in /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/encryption.cnf under the `[mysqld]` section but it appears to not be working. Am I just misreading the output below?

Other InnoDB tables are encrypted. [This note in the MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-data-encryption.html#innodb-data-encryption-undo-log) says, "When innodb_undo_log_encrypt is enabled, unencrypted undo log pages that are present on disk remain unencrypted, and new undo log pages are written to disk in encrypted form." But the flag in the conf file was set a month ago, with many writes in the interim.

No errors in the logs.

I am using MySQL 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3.

```
mysql> SELECT space, name, flag, (flag & 8192) AS encrypted FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_TABLESPACES WHERE NAME LIKE 'innodb_undo_%';
+------------+-----------------+------+-----------+
| space      | name            | flag | encrypted |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----------+
| 4294967279 | innodb_undo_001 |    0 |         0 |
| 4294967278 | innodb_undo_002 |    0 |         0 |
+------------+-----------------+------+-----------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "innodb_undo_log_encrypt";
+-------------------------+-------+
| Variable_name           | Value |
+-------------------------+-------+
| innodb_undo_log_encrypt | ON    |
+-------------------------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL>

root@db02:~# zgrep -i undo /var/log/mysql/error.log*
root@db02:~#
```

Comment: Please ask database admin related questions on the dedicated DBA sister-site of SO!

Comment: Thanks, I did not know such a place existed. I'll post it soon, they won't allow me to ask another question for the next 40 minutes :-/